# typeahead.js auto complete alternative for Web Interface

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

So I was planning on using [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) because it seemed fairly lightweight, however it's no longer supported, PRs go un-merged and looks dead in the water:

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/1562

I'm looking for an alternative to this, as lightweight as possible while supporting remote data sources in the same way typeahead.js does.

I am using bootstrap3 and returning JSON data from database queries for the autocomplete tool.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes the repo is as dead. Take a look https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js it's a fork of it that is maintained at the moment.